# angular 4 multi language and get data from database

Tags: angular

i want to add **multi language** functionality in angular 4, and get Data from Database(PostgreSQL).

1. with use of **ngx-translate** module we have to create .json files Language vise, but i want to fetch Localization(Data) from Database.

Comment: Have you found any high quality solution?

Comment: @WalterŁuszczyk still not

Answer (score -1):

I will assume that You have already succesfully loaded TranslateModule in your application(if not, here are [methods suggested by it's creator - they are great!](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#usage))

So to set your default language first thing is to inject `TranslateService` into your component that will be responsible for translation. Then in the constructor You will have to make some simple request to DB. Here's really simple concept how to solve it(example taken nearly 1 to 1 from ngx-translate docs):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
    <div>{{ 'HELLO' | translate:param }}</div>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
param = {value: 'world'};

constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    let lang;
    //here will be your request to recive language from DB
    translate.setDefaultLang(lang);
    // this language will be used as a fallback when a translation isn't found in the current language

    //of course do not forget about error handling if something fails!
    translate.use('en');
    // the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
    }
}
```

Go and do some research about [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate) it's really great and the authors provided some nice examples.

I know that I skipped actual request to DB but there's plenty of places to read about it, [like this one](https://angular.io/guide/http)(official Angular docs).